# Trying to avoid nested insert-exec using openrowset, but getting weird permissions error

Tags: sql-server, openrowset

I have a lot of databases, each with a bunch of stored procedures I need to run. These stored procedures run other procedures, which include insert exec statements. And I need to aggregate all of this data into a single dataset. I created dynamic SQL using `openrowset` to avoid nesting insert exec statements, and it worked for 90% of the stored procedures. All of the stored procedures are extremely similar (all using dynamic SQL to query tables local the server, but spread across several databases). All of the stored procedures that are failing include a cursor. That seems to be the only difference. Refactoring all of those stored procedures to avoid using a cursor would be a nightmare. The specific error message I am getting is this:

> Cannot process the object "{procedure name and parameters}". The OLE DB provider "MSOLEDBSQL" for linked server "(null)" indicates that either the object has no columns or the current user does not have permissions on that object.

If I run the stored procedure directly, it returns results. It just does not like being called via openrowset (using my Trusted Connection). Here is the Openrowset command:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI','Server={Servername};Database={DatabaseName};Trusted_Connection=yes;','exec {procedure name and parameters}')
```

But, the other nearly identical stored procedures all work fine with this query. I definitely have permissions to run that stored procedure, and the stored procedure definitely returns a result set with columns (and one row). Has anyone seen that error before? My searches have not been fruitful. Or is there a workaround for this?

Update 1: Here is a minimally reproducible example:

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;  
RECONFIGURE;
GO 
sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1;  
RECONFIGURE;  
GO 

CREATE TABLE FakeTable(ID INT, SomeData VARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO FakeTable(ID,SomeData)
VALUES(1,'Data1'),(2,'Data2'),(3,'Data3')
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.MyProc
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE aCursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT ID
    FROM FakeTable

    DECLARE @CurrID INT
    DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @Results TABLE(SomeData VARCHAR(50))

    OPEN aCursor
    FETCH NEXT FROM aCursor INTO @CurrID

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        SET @SQL = 'SELECT SomeData FROM FakeTable WHERE ID = ' + CAST(@CurrID AS VARCHAR)

        INSERT INTO @Results(SomeData)
        EXEC(@SQL)

        FETCH NEXT FROM aCursor INTO @CurrID
    END

    CLOSE aCursor
    DEALLOCATE aCursor

    SELECT *
    FROM @Results
END
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE myProc2
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT SomeData
    FROM FakeTable
END

GRANT EXECUTE ON dbo.myProc TO [public]
GO
GRANT EXECUTE ON dbo.myProc2 TO [public]
GO
GRANT SELECT ON FakeTable TO [public]
GO

--These three all work fine and return the same data set.
EXEC myProc
EXEC myProc2
SELECT *
FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI','Server={ServerName};Trusted_Connection=yes;Database={DatabaseName};','EXEC myProc2') a

/* This fails because of nested INSERT-EXEC
DECLARE @TempTable TABLE(SomeData VARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO @TempTable(SomeData)
EXEC myProc
*/

--This generates an error as well, for some reason.
SELECT *
FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI','Server={ServerName};Trusted_Connection=yes;Database={DatabaseName};','EXEC myProc') a

DROP PROCEDURE dbo.myProc
DROP PROCEDURE dbo.myProc2
DROP TABLE FakeTable
GO

sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 0;  
RECONFIGURE;  
GO 
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 0;  
RECONFIGURE;
GO
```

Comment: it will be helpful if you can provide a minimum reproducible example

Comment: You mean like a generic stored procedure with a cursor and I try openrowset on that? I'll give it a shot and post the code later today when I get to work.

Comment: Sounds like you have a design issue here

Comment: @Charlieface, yeah, but it is a design issue that is a decade old. There are hundreds of thousands of lines of code written on top of these design issues. It will take time to rewrite, and we need to use the system in the meantime. Rewrite efforts are definitely in progress!

Comment: To be honest, I would probably use client code such as C# or Python to pull together all these procedures. It's far easier than trying to do this in T-SQL

Comment: _And I need to aggregate all of this data into a single dataset_ Then you've chosen the wrong tool. Using tricks like this to overcome nested insert/execute statements is just that - a trick. Linked servers (yes - openquery is just dynamically creating short-lived ones) are notoriously fragile and can easily hide errors when multiple occur. You could try using profiler or equivalent to get more information about "why". But I doubt that will solve your issue.

Comment: @Charlieface that was my initial thought. A manager had a good reason why that is not an ideal solution.

Comment: @Smor that's a good idea. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: @Squirrel I added an example. The target server runs SQL Server 2019.

Comment: Hmm... it does not seem to be the cursor. I just found several stored procedures that include a cursor with the exact same structure as in my example, and they worked via openrowset. Now I'm very confused. I think I will push to use C# or Python, as Charlieface already suggested.

Comment: Possibly it needs to be the first statement in the batch, because it is using `sp_describe_first_result_set` to get the schema definition

Comment: @Charlieface This worked, and I'm up to like 97% passing. I used `WITH RESULT SETS` and that fixed most of the problems. But, I am still getting the same error for a couple of the queries... I'll need to review further.

Comment: I was allowed to write a c# program to handle this. I'm going to leave this question open because I am still surprised that it is failing and if anyone has an idea for how to work around it, it would be great to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this to double check the linked server is correctly identifying who you are:

```
SELECT X.* FROM 
        OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI','Server={Servername};Database={DatabaseName};Trusted_Connection=yes;', 
                     'SELECT SUSER_SNAME() AS LoginName;') as X
```

Comment: Yes, it returns my Active Directory login.